# Error Trying to Install Precompiled OpenCV 4.8 on Raspberry Pi 4 64Bit

Tags: opencv

I was recently shown a method to install a precompiled version of OpenCV from the following link: [Install Precompiled OpenCV 4.8 on Raspberry Pi](https://lindevs.com/install-precompiled-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/)

When I run the command `sudo apt install -y ./opencv_64.deb` I'm met with

```
Note, selecting 'opencv:arm64' instead of './opencv_64.deb Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies:opencv:arm64 : Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:arm64 (>= 1.18.4) but it is not installable
            Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:arm64 (>= 1.18.4) but it is not installable
            Depends: libavcodec58:arm64 (>= 4.3.2)
            Depends: libavformat58:arm64 (>= 4.3.2) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libavutil56:arm64 (>= 4.3.2) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libswscale5:arm64 (>= 4.3.2) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-numpy:arm64 (>= 1.19.5) but it is not installable  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does anyone know how to fix, I'm new to Pi and OpenCV so any help is massive appreciated.

Comment: You haven't mentioned Bullseye or Bookworm.

Comment: That is an essential question @toyotaSupra, because the install link say: Binaries are compatible with Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye (32-bit and 64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

There is already a precompiled version in the repository (admittedly v4.6).

Run `sudo apt install python3-opencv`

As an aside I am not sure that you can use `apt` to install local deb - I always use `dpkg`, but there is no point in this case.

Unless you have a very good reason for installing a later version than provided by Debian stick with the package version.